# Get the path to a folder with only the file name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating the game engine and the files are structured like this:

```
/Game
    game.py
    /PyEngine
        __init__.py
        main.py
        /dict
            __init__.py
            dict_entity.py
            dict_map.py
            etc
        /lib
            __init__.py
            entity.py
            map.py
            etc
    /Graphics
        /entity
            /player
                /player_stand.png
                /player_run.png
                etc
```

Now, to import modules into "game.py" or "main.py" it's simple... The problem is, if I wish, for example, to import "entity_dict.py" into "entity.py" how should I do? And if instead you want, in "entity.py", upload the file "player_stand.png", how should I do? More than anything else, I would like "entity.py" to get the path of "player_stand.png" having just the name. In this way, if the file is not present (for example, it was deleted incorrectly), I can give the error to the player. I searched the net, but I did not find solutions that could approach my question, so I ask you for advice.

Comment: to get `play_stand.png` from `game.py`: `os.path.join(os.path.basename(__file__), "Graphics", "player", "player_stand.png")`

Comment: unfortunately I need the path of "player_stand.png" in "entity.py"

Comment: that's not much harder: `os.path.join(os.path.basename(__file__), "..", "..", "Graphics", "player", "player_stand.png")`

Comment: The `basename`s should probably be `dirname`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, if I wish, for example, to import "entity_dict.py" into "entity.py" how should I do?

Given the project structure

```
/base
    main_script.py

    /parentpackage
        __init__.py

        /childpackage1
            __init__.py
            mod1.py

        /childpackage2
            __init__.py
            mod2.py
```

And you want to import `mod1` from `mod2`, you have two options.

Using relative imports

```
from ..childpackage1 import mod1
```

Using absolute imports

```
from parentpackage.childpackage1 import mod1
```

Both will work.

The former requires `parentpackage` to be a package (including a `__init__.py` file), otherwise you'll get an error like: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

The latter doesn't have this restriction, but if you ever rename parent package, you'd have to go in and update all of the imports (who didn't really care about `parentpackage` in the first place, and were just using it to get into `childpackage1`).

Since, in your case, `parentpackage` is a proper package, the first option is preferred.

> More than anything else, I would like "entity.py" to get the path of "player_stand.png" having just the name.

This is more straightforward -- you might look into the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html) module.

Edit:

You could use the following functions to turn a filename into an absolute path name.

```
import os
import glob

GRAPHICS_PATH = <something>

def get_graphic_path(*parts):
    return os.path.join(GRAPHICS_PATH, *parts)

def find_graphic_path(filename):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(GRAPHICS_PATH, '**', filename), recursive=True)
```

How you define `GRAPHICS_PATH` is up to you, and depends on a lot of things.  You could hard code it as a string (absolute or relative).  You could use `__file__` or `sys.argv[0]` along with some combination of `os.path.join` and `os.path.dirname` to define it relative to either (a) the file these functions appear in or (b) your game.py script, respectively.

Comment: how does glob help to get `player_stand.png`?

Comment: @MatthewStory OP is looking for a file, by name only, in some subdirectory of a known directory.  That seems like `glob` to me.

Comment: why? the OP knows the directory, the filename and has access to `__file__` in a module that has a fixed relative relationship to the target file. `glob` is irrelevant to the question. It can be done with `os.path.join(os.path.basename(__file__), "relative", "paths", "to.png")`. If you don't like `os` use `pathlib`, but  `glob` is for expanding paths based on patterns.

Comment: It's possible that I misread it, or the OP wasn't clear, but *get the path of "player_stand.png" **having just the name*** sounds like they *don't* have the "fixed relative relationship" you suggest, IMO.

Comment: the entire directory structure is clearly outlined in the question.

Comment: I looked for the module, but I have to say, for example, "../*/*/*/player_stand.png". I would rather that in entity.py, given the name, look for the file in the game folder (regardless of where the game folder is in the computer) and get the path of the file. In this way, if the file has been moved, but is still in the folder, the module "entity.py" can still use it. If it is not present, then the module will react accordingly.

Comment: This need arose from the fact that at the beginning, the files in lib and in dict were together with "main.py". Then creating this structure, I had the problem that in "entity_dict.py" there was the path of the original image. I modified it, but I kept getting error. So, I thought about putting only the name and it looks for the path from "entity.py". In this way, in addition to the reasons mentioned above, if you move in the future "entity.py", the module would still be able to find what it needs.